# Rounded Text Font from Xcode Storyboard

Tags: xcode

It's easy to use a rounded font design with the `font(.system(.body, design: .rounded))` modifier. How can I accomplish the same style in the Xcode Storyboard panel? I'm assuming I need to use the System font, but I see no setting to set "rounded". I would do this in code, but I would like to make this change in the launch screen.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no storyboard access to the system font "design" variants. Even if you use an attributed string and set the font to the SF Pro Rounded variant, you will still see the normal SF Pro in the interface:

[image]

(As you can see, it's rounded on the right, in the inspector, but not in the label — and not in the label when the app runs.)

So code is the only way. This would make a good use case for an enhancement request that you file with Apple.